# One class that inherits another is not recognised as a type

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm new to C++ and as a sort of "learning experience" I'm porting an old console 'game' I made in C#.

At the moment, I'm using g++ 4.9.1 under Ubuntu 14.10.

I have a header file that defines some types such as `Item`, `HealingItem` (which inherits Item), and `Weapon` which inherits Item also.

I later reference these types in another header file which I have added the proper `#include` to, in this case an `Entity` class which defines `Player` which has an `Items::Weapon _equippedWeapon`.

Interestingly enough, the compiler does not seem to recognise `Items::Weapon` as a type, which in theory shouldn't be a problem considering `Weapon` inherits `Item` (`Items::Item` compiles fine if I change the specific line to that, but `Items::HealingItem` DOESN'T)

Am I missing something more here? I can post full source code if requested.

Here's the full message from running `make` on my project:

```
error: 'Weapon' in namespace 'Items' does not name a type
    Items::Weapon _equippedWeapon;
           ^
```

and just for quick reference, i have my namespace set up as follows

```
namespace Items
{
        class Item;
        class HealingItem;
        class Weapon;
}
//some code cut out for obvious reasons, i'll just show the basic class constructors for the classes
class Items::Item
{
public:
        Item();
//...
};
class Items::HealingItem: public Items::Item
{
//...
public:
        HealingItem();
};
class Items::Weapon: public Items::Item
{
public:
        Weapon();
//...other properties and get/setters
};
```

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

My inherited classes are not being recognised as types.

For example, when I declare the variable `Items::Item`, the program compiles fine. However, right when I change it to `Items::Weapon` which is derived from `Items::Item` that's when the compiler errors come in. The problem is, how can I get the compiler to begin to recognise `Items::Weapon` as its own type?

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5d8d9b3e4f82d5a0) modulo three missing semicolons. Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can't tell what's going on from the code you posted, but aren't you by chance establishing an `#include` loop?

Comment: @T.C. will do, give me a few

Comment: @AndyProwl could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @MrMiketheripper: Do you have a file A.h which includes a file B.h and viceversa (B.h includes A.h)? The mutual inclusion may even be indirect, through another header C.h. Try looking for `#include` loops

Comment: @AndyProwl I do have main.cpp which `#include "Item.h"` and also some of the other .cpp that inherit `Item.h` also, does that classify as such?

Comment: @MrMiketheripper No. Just look for header inclusion loops (A.h includes B.h, B.h includes C.h, C.h includes ..., ... includes A.h). If you don't have anything like that, just forget my comment :) It was only a blind guess, since the problem is in the code you didn't post.

Comment: @AndyProwl nope, problem isn't there. thank you though, i'll now do my best to be aware of that in the future ;)